# c# property Setter not work for my component

Tags: c#, components, setter

I'm designing a component for myself. One property of the component is "Status" which has the type "StatusClass".

MyCode is:

```
private StatusClass _mStatus=new StatusClass();
public StatusClass Status
{
    get { return this._mStatus; }
    set
    {
        this._mStatus = value;
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

the problem is that the setter/"Refresh" method does not call when one property of StatusClass changes.
for example:

```
myComponent.Status.proprety1 = 3;  // the "Refresh method not call
```

but:

```
myComponent.Status = new StatusClass(); // the "Refresh method called
```

how can I correctly define the Status property so that by changing its value, the setter function be called.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The refresh method is called when the instance of `Status` is updated to new object as you have defined it in setter `this.Refresh();`.

```
myComponent.Status = new StatusClass(); // the "Refresh method called
```

And it will not be called by this line

```
myComponent.Status.proprety1 = 3;  // the "Refresh method not call
```

as here you are **updating the property** of `Status` instead of object itself.

To achieve that even on change of Properties of `Status` class, the notification should be received at invoker class, then you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`   interface which assist to notify clients that a property value has changed. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class StatusClass  : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    private int proprety1 
    public int Proprety1 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.proprety1;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.proprety1)
            {
                this.proprety1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now at invoker class you can define the object as

```
public class DemoClass
{
     private StatusClass _mStatus = new StatusClass();

     public DemoClass()
     {
          _mStatus.PropertyChanged = (sender, args) => { this.Refresh(); }
     }
}
```

So when now `myComponent.Status.Proprety1 = 3;` is called, the Refresh will be invoked as it has subscribed for property changed of `StatusClass`.